# data exchange between Chrome and ARC application

Tags: android, google-chrome, google-chrome-arc

Say, I have an Android application wrapped into ARC package and I want to get some information, which can be fetched by running some JavaScript code in Chrome console, e.g, I want to fetch `navigator.userAgent`.

Is there a way to do it?